# UITableView editing Doubts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

i have this code for deleting the cell content from database

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [appDelegate.indexArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        [appDelegate.notesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        [tableViewObj reloadData];
        NSString *DataPath = [MyBibleAppAppDelegate getPath];
        [appDelegate.data writeToFile:DataPath atomically:YES];
        [tableViewObj reloadData];
    } 
}
```

it works perfect but i need to put the above code in my button click ,i put this in button click

```
-(IBAction)_clickbtndeltNoteall:(id)sender
{
            [appDelegate.indexArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
            [appDelegate.notesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
            [tableViewObj reloadData];
            NSString *DataPath = [MyBibleAppAppDelegate getPath];
            [appDelegate.data writeToFile:DataPath atomically:YES];
            [tableViewObj reloadData];
}
```

But I got this error: "Undeclared identifier indexpath". How to solve this?

Comment: defiantly you will get like that ..take one NSIndexPath object in .h file and assign value in commitEditingStyle method and use that object in your button action method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest saving the indexPath for the pressed row in a singleton. Here is a guide on how to use the [singleton class](http://pixeleap.com/?p=19) to store objects and use them across classes.

In this example you can also just declare an instance variable and set it when the row is pressed in the appropriate delegate method for your *UITableView*. This could be done like so:

```
@interface

NSIndexPath *tableViewPath;
```

---

```
@implementation

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

tableViewPath = indexPath;

}
```

Your action for your button should now look like this:

```
- (IBAction)_clickbtndeltNoteall:(id)sender
{
       [appDelegate.indexArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
       [appDelegate.notesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
       [tableViewObj reloadData];
       NSString *DataPath = [MyBibleAppAppDelegate getPath];
       [appDelegate.data writeToFile:DataPath atomically:YES];
       [tableViewObj reloadData];
}
```

The code for the button assumes that a row have been selected before it is pressed. You could also initialize your *indexPath* in the *viewDidLoad*
like so:

```
@implementation

- (void)viewDidLoad {

tableViewPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

}
```

You should adjust your initialization to what would be appropriate for your specific program!

Answer (score 1):

What cell do you want to remove when the button is clicked?

Add:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToDelete inSection:sectionToDelete];
```

On the top of your method.

Comment: Thats obviously not a good solution, as it's not for sure what row he needs to delete? Also a local declaration of the NSIndexPath is a bad idea. An instance variable should be used for this.

Comment: You mean he should keep a NSIndexPath instance on his controller just to know which index to delete? I agree he doesn't need NSIndexPath, but I can assure you an instance variable is should NOT be used for this.

Comment: If he wants to keep the index of the row throughout his whole class I guess it would be ideal?

Comment: Why would the controller object have a indexPath as a attribute?

Comment: As mentioned in my post, he could use a singleton to store it.

Comment: Using a singleton for this is just wrong on a OO language. But ok, suit yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`indexPath` is not defined in `_clickbtndeltNoteall`, that's why you get that error.

You may do something like

```
-(IBAction)_clickbtndeltNoteall:(id)sender
{
        [appDelegate.indexArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        [appDelegate.notesArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        [tableViewObj reloadData];
        NSString *DataPath = [MyBibleAppAppDelegate getPath];
        [appDelegate.data writeToFile:DataPath atomically:YES];
        [tableViewObj reloadData];
}
```

where `index` is defined somewhere else (a class field for example). You can use an auxiliary method to set `index` to specify the section you want to delete, then call `_clickbtndeltNoteall`

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing to the indexPath variable inside your -(IBAction)_clickbtndeltNoteall:(id)sender, and that's not possible because the variable doesnt exist in that scope.

Why dont you store the last indexPath in a global variable, and then you access to it? Something like this:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {      
        lastIndexPath = indexPath;
        //Your code
        }
}
```

And in your interfaz declaration, you put:

```
NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)_clickbtndeltNoteall:(id)sender
{    
UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *clickedButtonPath = [tableViewObj indexPathForCell:clickedCell];
    int section1=clickedButtonPath.section;
 [appDelegate.indexArray removeObjectAtIndex:section1];
            [appDelegate.notesArray removeObjectAtIndex:section1];
            [tableViewObj reloadData];
            NSString *DataPath = [MyBibleAppAppDelegate getPath];
            [appDelegate.data writeToFile:DataPath atomically:YES];
            [tableViewObj reloadData];
}
```

It will surely work if the button is on the cell itself..If button is not on the cell then you can directly pass the indexpath without specifying uitableviewcell... try it..